# Changing the orientation of an Interface Builder Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard

I have a .storyboard file whose orientation I need to change from portrait to landscape so that it wouldn't just stretch the scene as the app is landscape only.
How can I modify this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the ViewController bar (bottom, under the view), then go to Attribute Inspector, and in Simulated Metrics > Orientation select Landscape.

Comment: Although now with Freeform as a view size option, you have to make sure None is selected, or it won't rotate.

Comment: It's not there anymore

Comment: @Dustin Yes, same here. Can't find any orientation setting anymore and the storyboard ignores my project settings (only landscape allowed). XCode 8.1

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825425/ios-set-storyboard-orientation-to-landscape Solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of views to change :

- Right click on the storyboard -> open as source code and replace this line :

  ```
  <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
  ```

by

```
<simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation" orientation="landscapeRight"/>
```

or

```
<simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation" orientation="landscapeLeft"/>
```

or other depending of what you need