# iOs set Storyboard orientation to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, orientation, xcode8

I wish to set View Controller's orientation as **landscape** in Storyboard. I referred the below links but couldn't find the "orientation" option anywhere (screenshot attached)
[image]

**Links referred:**

[Designing in landscape with Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599195/designing-in-landscape-with-storyboards)

[iOS 7 XCode 5 Storyboard set orientation to Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495340/ios-7-xcode-5-storyboard-set-orientation-to-landscape)

Comment: in which xcode verson r u used

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In xcode 8 the option to change the orientation is not from Inspector, you will be able to change the orientation from bottom bar, please check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: great and where to find this, I don't see this at the bottom, we have somehow to expand it, but you didn't tell about it anything, not an answer

Comment: @user924 while on the Storyboard, click on the bottom at: "View as: iPhone ..." and it will open you the menu

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 8 provides the option for landscape orientation from Storyboard itself.[image]